# .htaccess redirects to 404 issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, slug

I've been trying to remove slug from custom post types in WordPress using htaccess,
Insted of using:
`domain.com/portfolio/item`
I'm trying to get:
`domain.com/item`

- I'm not an htaccess expert but after reading a bit I tried this:
  `RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

When I was trying to get to a link with the following format:
`domain.com/item`
I had no problem, the problem started when a trailing slash was joining:
`domain.com/item/`
It just takes me to a 404 error page.

Does someone have an idea why it's happening? -_-
Thanks.

Comment: Did you set a default document in the webserver? If you can't access the webserver, do you have an index.html / index.php?

Comment: You mean within the htaccess file? I have the default rewrites that comes with WordPress.

Comment: no within the directory, does domain.com/item/index.html exist?

Comment: nope, so I wrote it wrong?
It first gets into the portfolio item but when I do a refresh or pastes a link with a trailing slash it throws me to a 404 page. :\

Comment: Could you post your document tree? show us which files you have and in which folders etc..

Comment: Ok so I figured that my problem is on those rules that I have created for my site migration:
`RewriteRule ^portfolio/old-page/?$ "\/destination-page/" [R=301,L]`  for all those old pages that I need to redirect to the new format. The rules that I've posted before are actually working great, tried to add string after the trailing slash and it gets me to 404 but if I only add a trailing slash it gets me to the right destination. what should I change in the other redirect rules to get them working?

Comment: Can you try: `RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.+?)/?$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: I've added the question mark, it works but I figured that the problem appears only on certain pages. that the rule for them is:  `RewriteRule ^portfolio/old-page/?$ "\/destination-page/" [R=301,L]`  when I go to: `domain.com/destination-page` it works perfect,but when I'm adding any trailing slash it throws me to a 404 page. it doesn't happen with all the pages, only with the articles. -_- any idea?